# dxgrid binding cell colour to string value

Tags: wpf, devexpress, mvvm-light

I have a DXgrid using the mvvm light toolkit that displays a list of objects from a webservice.

one of the properties of the object is a Colour field. I want to be able to colour a cell that colour.

I have tried by painting a rectangle inside a cell, but no luck

```
 <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" AutoPopulateColumns="True" Height="412" Name="grdLicence" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Cars}" 
                     DesignTimeDataObjectType="{Binding Model.Cars}" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=Id}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="ID"/>
                            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=LicenseDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LicenseDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Header="Type" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="30">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Colour}"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>

                        </Rectangle>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>

            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=Province}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Province}" Header="Province" />


        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" AutoWidth="True" ShowSearchPanelMode="Always" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Selection}" MultiSelectMode="Row" NavigationStyle="Row"   FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  />


        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

if i hardcode the colour it works, but not via binding. property name is correct
Thanks!

---

ok getting further, i am using the cellpropperty instead, and using a converter, but for some weird reason the converter doesnt fire. i have a breakpoint in it, but it never ets hit

```
     <UserControl.Resources>

    <views:ColourConverter x:Key="clrc"/>

    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:CellContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Colour, Converter={StaticResource clrc}}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

//note Colour is the field name.

Comment: Can you use DataTemplate instead of ControlTemplate?

Comment: i could, assuming i knew how. i am new to devExpress. btw i have the colour name as a string if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you bind a Color property to a string property, it wont work. The program doesnt know how to convert it, so you have to tell him with a [IValueConverter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html):

```
public class StringToColorConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(value.ToString());
        if (color != null)
            return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));

        return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

If it still doesnt work, place a breakpoint in the Convert-method a have a look if it gets entered.

Comment: thanks. makes a lot of sense. i am still not  coming right tho. as u said the breakpoint isnt getting hit. is the xaml being declared correctly?    <UserControl.Resources>

        <views:ColourConverter x:Key="clrc"/>

        <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:CellContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Colour, Converter={StaticResource clrc}}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

Comment: Looks good, try adding `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` to your Value-binding.

Comment: Does your Colour-property raises the PropertyChanged Event in the setter? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: hmmm, ok i think we might be onto something. no it doesnt. also, it doesnt have a setter / readonly calculated field. only has a getter

Comment: you dont have to call the OnPropertyChanged-event in the setter. if its a readonly calculated property call it wherever the value changes.

Comment: i think thats a red herring. binding to a property that does implement onpropertychanged event also doesnt kick off the converter

Comment: If you call `OnPropertyChanged("Colour");` the binding updates and the converter is entered, no matter where you call it (as long as you call it in the same class where the property is);